# Multilanguage. Записать HTML тэг в объект

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, multilanguage

Делаю сайт с возможностью перевода на несколько языков. Переводы делаю таким образом

```js
$(function() {
  $('.translate').click(function() {
    var lang = $(this).attr('id');

    $('.lang').each(function(index, element) {
      $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var arrLang = {
  'ru': {
    'title': 'Some text ru',
    'subtitle': 'Some text ru ru'
  
  },
  'ua': {
    'title': 'some text ua',
    'subtitle': 'some text ua'
  }
  
  };
</script>
<h1 key="title" class="lang">Some text</h1>
<h2 key="subtitle" class="lang">Some text double</h2>


<button class="translate" id="ru">RU</button>
<button class="translate" id="ua">UA</button>
```

Но есть проблема: она заключается в том, что если есть вложенность например такая - `<li> bla bla <span>some text</span> continue</li>`, то непонятно как переводить части перед спаном и после него. Либо же весь текст до спана и после спана оборачивать в какой-то тег и давать ему ключ.

Собственно вопрос: возможно ли как-то в объект записывать тег вида: `Some text <span>400</span>` и чтоб он в переведенном виде отображался корректно?
Для этого нужно его как-то обрабатывать, но вот как... или может есть другое решение мультиязычности?

Заранее благодарен.

UPD.
В MVC есть такая штука как `@Html.Raw`, тогда можно в файлы ресурсов записывать вложенные теги и вообще HTML. Вот если бы был какой-то аналог этого трюка в jQuery, было бы прекрасно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этого сделать в данной реализации нельзя.
Придется создавать несколько `inline` элементов внутри одного блочного и каждому из них давать уникальный ключ.